# Removing header column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

df

```
   A   B
0  23  12
1  21  44
2  98  21
```

How do I remove the column names `A` and `B` from this dataframe? One way might be to write it into a csv file and then read it in specifying header=None. is there a way to do that without writing out to csv and re-reading?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: I have a function that assumes that they are not present

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(df.values)`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think you cant remove column names, only reset them by `range` with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
print df.shape[1]
2

print range(df.shape[1])
[0, 1]

df.columns = range(df.shape[1])
print df
    0   1
0  23  12
1  21  44
2  98  21
```

This is same as using [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
print df.to_csv(header=None,index=False)
23,12
21,44
98,21

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u""+df.to_csv(header=None,index=False)), header=None)
    0   1
0  23  12
1  21  44
2  98  21
```

Next solution with `skiprows`:

```
print df.to_csv(index=False)
A,B
23,12
21,44
98,21

print pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u""+df.to_csv(index=False)), header=None, skiprows=1)
    0   1
0  23  12
1  21  44
2  98  21
```

Comment: That is a very smart way to recount row or column index

Answer (score 27):

How to get rid of a header(first row) and an index(first column).

To write to CSV file:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(your_array)
df.to_csv('your_array.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

To read from CSV file:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('your_array.csv')
a = df.values
```

If you want to read a CSV file that doesn't contain a header, pass additional parameter `header`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('your_array.csv', header=None)
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem but solved it in this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your-array.csv', skiprows=[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen this solution yet so here's how I did it without using read_csv:

```
df.rename(columns={'A':'','B':''})
```

If you rename all your column names to empty strings your table will return without a header.

And if you have a lot of columns in your table you can just create a dictionary first instead of renaming manually:

```
df_dict = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, '')
df.rename(columns = df_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the DataFrame to an Numpy array, using this:

s1=df.iloc[:,0:2].values

Then, convert the numpy array back to DataFrame:

s2=pd.DataFrame(s1)

This will return a DataFrame with no Columns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ2iF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

To get the dataframe without the header use:

```
totalRow = len(df.index)
df.iloc[1: totalRow]
```

Or you can use the second method like this:

```
totalRow = df.index.stop
df.iloc[1, totalRow]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing header column from pandas DataFrame. It can be done without writing out to csv and then reading again.

Solution:

Replace the column names by first row of the DataFrame.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:].values
```

and then delete that first row of DataFrame.

```
df = df.tail(-1)
```