# delete first row of dataframe which is not indexed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, title

I have a table in dataframe form, in python.

```
                                Weekly report 7 - 2011 Unnamed: 1  ...            Unnamed: 24            Unnamed: 25
0   (**) Please note that this applies only to "Mo...        NaN  ...                    NaN                    NaN
1                                       Type of alert       Type  ...  Production dates (**)  Packaging description
2                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
3                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
4                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
5                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
6                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
7                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
8                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
9                                        Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
10                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
11                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
12                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
13                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
14                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                      -                    NaN
15                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
16                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
17                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
18                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
19                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
20                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
21                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
22                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
23                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
24                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
25                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
26                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
27                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
28                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
29                                       Serious risk   Consumer  ...                    NaN                    NaN
```

I try to remove the first two lines. I tried all the mentioned ways in the internet, but it just removes the second line. I used iloc, drop, etc. But the first line which starts with ''Weekly report 7'' is always there. Please help me.

Comment: Those are your column names.

Comment: I guess you cant remove column names, only reset them by range with shape
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688022/removing-header-column-from-pandas-dataframe/44731471